# Convert pandas dataframe column labels from float to integer

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, int

I have the following snippet of the pandas **dataframe** 'GDP', where the column labels are floats.

```
3        2013.0        2014.0        2015.0  
4           NaN           NaN           NaN  
5  3.127550e+09           NaN           NaN  
6  1.973134e+10  1.999032e+10  2.029415e+10  
7  9.626143e+10  1.008863e+11  1.039106e+11  
8  1.254247e+10  1.279331e+10  1.312082e+10
```

I have tried to convert these float labels to integers with the following but did not succeed:

```
GDP.columns = GDP.columns.astype(int)
```

I keep getting the error: **TypeError: Cannot cast Index to dtype**

I then want to convert this to a string (like the following):

```
years = np.arange(2006, 2016).astype(str)
GDP = GDP[np.append(['Country'],years)]
```

Thus, my overall dataframe should look something like this:
[image]

Could anyone give me a helping hand?

`print(GDP.columns)` looks like this:

```
Index([       'Country',   'Country Code', 'Indicator Name', 'Indicator Code',
                 1960.0,           1961.0,           1962.0,           1963.0,
                 1964.0,           1965.0,           1966.0,           1967.0,
                 1968.0,           1969.0,           1970.0,           1971.0,
                 1972.0,           1973.0,           1974.0,           1975.0,
                 1976.0,           1977.0,           1978.0,           1979.0,
                 1980.0,           1981.0,           1982.0,           1983.0,
                 1984.0,           1985.0,           1986.0,           1987.0,
                 1988.0,           1989.0,           1990.0,           1991.0,
                 1992.0,           1993.0,           1994.0,           1995.0,
                 1996.0,           1997.0,           1998.0,           1999.0,
                 2000.0,           2001.0,           2002.0,           2003.0,
                 2004.0,           2005.0,           2006.0,           2007.0,
                 2008.0,           2009.0,           2010.0,           2011.0,
                 2012.0,           2013.0,           2014.0,           2015.0],
      dtype='object', name=3)
```

Comment: What is `print (Reducedset.columns)` ?

Comment: @jezrael I have ammended the code above to show print(GDP.columns)

Comment: GDP.columns gives you the column names. Try GDP.astype(int)

Comment: @formicaman thanks! the solution below works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert only numeric columns, here it means all columns after first 4. column and join together:

```
GDP.columns = GDP.columns[:4].tolist() + GDP.columns[4:].astype(int).astype(str).tolist()
```

And then:

```
years = np.arange(2006, 2016).astype(str)
GDP = GDP[np.append(['Country'],years)]
```

Comment: thanks so much! In python should the data type of every column label be the same?

Comment: @Caledonian26 - I think no, each columns should be different type.

Comment: @Caledonian26 - But if need convert all columns togetehr, is necessary same type.

Comment: Yes I then converted: GDP.columns = GDP.columns.astype(str) and then continued with my formula and it worked nicely!

Comment: see my answer overall below!

Comment: @Caledonian26 - it is possible simplify, edited answer.

Comment: yes perfect! Thanks a lot! Your help is always invaluable!

Answer (score 0):

```py
GDP.columns = GDP.columns.map(int)
```

If you have numeric column labels mixed in with string labels:

```py
for ind, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    if col.isdigit():
        df.columns.values[ind] = int(col)
```